# Influence of Edmund Landau's list of four problems

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, open-problems

At the 1912 International Congress of Mathematicians, Edmund Landau listed [four basic problems about prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems): Goldbach's conjecture, the twin prime conjecture, Legendre's conjecture (that there always exists a prime number between consecutive perfect squares), and whether there are infinitely many prime numbers of the form $n^2 + 1$.

Although I had heard of each of these conjectures individually, I only recently learned of the existence of Landau's list, from a [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/436257/).  My question, broadly speaking, is how famous and/or influential was Landau's list?  To be more specific:

> What are some number theory textbooks or research papers that cite Landau's list by name, or credit him with popularizing these particular conjectures?

Comment: Please document preliminary research. What did you find when you searched Google Scholar and Google Books? What information should be covered by an answer here that goes beyond the information found in such an online search?

Comment: @njuffa The Wikipedia article lists several research papers that have proved partial results on the four conjectures. I looked at several of the most prominent ones, but none of them mentioned Landau's list. I have also read or browsed dozens of number theory textbooks over the years but do not recall Landau's list ever being mentioned (but maybe I missed it). If someone can name just one number theory textbook or research paper that cites Landau's list by name, that would be a satisfactory answer. I don't think that it's easy to do this with a quick online search.

Comment: My take based on searching Google Scholar and Google Books: There seems to be no awareness of "Landau's problems" as a collective list in literature prior to the year 2000. There are no citations, no references to it best I can tell. Even thereafter, there are scarce references only. I think it is fair to conclude that Landau's list as such was neither influential nor famous, nor even widely known, and pretty much ignored for almost a hundred years. Not that it matters, but I learned about it from the question here, despite some past interest in prime numbers.